# DB Conect Class Error

Tags: php, class, dbconnection

```
class DB 
{
    private static $_instance;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct()
    {   
       try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
       } catch(PDOException $e)
       {
        die($e->getMessage()); 
       }
    }

    private static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

}
```

When I try to get the instance using $db = DB::getInstance(); I get: Fatal error: Call to private method DB::getInstance() from context ''

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `catch` and `die` does not make any sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know about [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) and simple pattern [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
Replace

```
private static function getInstance()
```

With

```
public static function getInstance()
```

Also. Where do you consider to take params for PDO?

Answer (score 0):

You are using DB class as an abstract class, you should create an object of it. and you should also pass $dsn, $user, $password.

```
class DB 
{
    private static $_instance;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
        $_count = 0;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $password)
    {   
       try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
       } catch(PDOException $e)
       {
        die($e->getMessage()); 
       }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
 }
```

Usage

```
 $db = DB('dsn','user','password');
 $db->getInstance()
```

If i am wrong sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @sectus pointed out, a constructor will never return anything so 
`self::$_instance = new DB();` does not make sense really, consider moving that logic to the function itself:

```
if(!isset(self::$_instance))
{
    try{
        self::$_instance = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage()); 
    }
}
```